# Efficient method to determine minimum eigenvalue of $2 \times 2$ block diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $H$ is a $2 \times 2$ block-diagonal symmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{2^N \times 2^N} $. That is

$$ H  = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & A_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
                        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{2^{N-1}} \\  \end{pmatrix}$$

where each $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} $. Then we know that the eigenvalues of $H$ are the eigenvalues of each individual block $A_i$ since
$ \textrm{det}(H-\lambda I) = \prod_i (A_i - \lambda I) $. However, this requires solving  $2^{N-1}$ eigenvalue problems of size $2 \times 2$. Thus, determining the minimum eigenvalue of $H$ result in an exponential cost in $N$, $O(2^N)$ to be specific.

***Question:*** Is there a an **efficient** way to determine the minimum eigenvalue of $H$? That is, the method should yield a cost of $O(poly(N))$.

Comment: Even if the $A_j$ are $1\times 1$ matrices, you need to inspect all $2^N$ numbers to determine which is the smallest one, so this doesn't sound plausible.

Comment: @ChristianRemling True. Point taken. Thanks.

Comment: Your indexing and your counting seem inconsistent. From the way you've indexed the $A_i $, it's a $2N\times 2N$ matrix, not a $2^N \times 2^N $ one. Maybe your problem only costs $O(N)$ after all?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt That was my mistake. Sorry. It should run through $2^{N-1}$.

Comment: Your only chance is if the diagonal blocks follow some sort of pattern, for example they depend on a parameter in some simple way.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the matrix $H$ is tridiagonal. For Toeplitz or symmetric tridiagonal matrices, there are Eigenvalue algorithms faster than $O(n^2)$, despite not being in $O(poly(N))$, c. f. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues

Comment: @user7427029: The $n$ in this link corresponds to $2^N$ here.

Comment: @ChristianRemling You are right.